# XML Sitemap Generator for URL with 1.5 million pages?

Tags: xml, sitemap

I am trying to create an XML Sitemap for Bloomberg Businessweek, specifically all pages that begin with:

http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=

It's my understanding that there are approximately 1.5 million pages that begin with this prefix.  Is it even possible to create an XML Sitemap for this many pages?

Comment: You could try GSiteCrawler, A1 Sitemap Generator (you will have to switch off some data collection options and may also need to do some other configuration, e.g. to limit analysis/output to the wanted URLs) and other tools (search Google) - try ask the vendors

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. It is just a question of writing a crawler (if you don't have access to the Database with the content) and the generatiion of a xml file. (Don't use an DOM based XML api, because of the memory consumption for large files).

But what do you want to do with a File of min `100 MB` size [1].

I don't think that this file would be helpful at all.

1) explaination:

```
1.500.000 pages * (length of URL + 100 Bytes XML overhead)
```

Comment: Ultimately, I want the XML file so I can extract the identification numbers which are embedded in the URLs.  Each company covered by this website has its own page, so in theory an XML file for all pages whose URL begins with my example would contain the ID numbers for every company they cover.  Is there a product out there that does this?  I tried one product but it runs out of resources after collecting approximately 500,000 pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it using xml generator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).